# Find non-blank visible cells without looping

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in a table (ListObject) which may or may not be valued and may or may not be visible (dues to filtering).

I thought I could use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` to do this without looping. The problem is that the cell value is determined by a formula that is basically `=IF(true,"value","")`.

So SpecialCells doesn't seem to have a way to distinguish between a logical blank (ie, "") and a logical constant ("value")

Anyone have a native way to return only cells that have a "value" without looping? I am using the following loop in the mean time.

```
Function GetValuedCells(aRange As Excel.Range) As Excel.Range
    If aRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    Dim rngCell As Excel.Range
    For Each rngCell In aRange
        If IsValued(rngCell.Value2) Then
            If GetValuedCells Is Nothing Then Set GetValuedCells = rngCell
            Set GetValuedCells = Union(GetValuedCells, rngCell)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: `xlCellTypeFormulas` is for formulas. Maybe filter the blanks and just `xlCellTypeVisible`

Comment: Does this help?  https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/7/21/selecting-non-blank-cells

Comment: @flaZer Good try, but It helps only to confirm that what I want to do is likely not possible. As the author of that article states "Note that if a formula outputs a blank value (ie "") then it WILL BE included in the..."

Comment: I don't know what `IsValued()` does since the code is missing. But why not put the range into an array and loop it through. The performance of arrays is blazing fast and you will barely notice the loop.